# Porque me aparece error de ruta en este batch

Tags: cmd, batch

estoy haciendo un launcher en batch que tendra un menu con el cual abrire distintos juegos, mi idea es hacer un batch que inicie cada juego y llamarlos con el comando "call".
no se porque pero he intentado varias formas y en todas me tira el mismo error(dejo captura abajo)

este es el código, hace unos días hice un batch de automatización que me abre el chrome y spotify al encender el pc, no tuve problema usando START y el nombre del programa sin necesidad de especificar la ruta (en ese escenario Chrome.exe y Spotify.exe)

```
@echo off
start Blasphemous.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\DODI-Repacks\Blasphemous 
exit
```

el mismo error me aparece con otros programas, porque puede ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguramente `Blasphemous.exe` este en una carpeta distinta desde dónde estás ejecutando el comando o no tienes el EXE en el path.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quieras ejecutar un programa, le vas a decir a la consola la ubicación completa de dicho archivo:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\DODI-Repacks\Blasphemous\Blasphemous.exe"
exit
```

Si le dices que ejecute Blasphemous.exe  sin siquiera decirle donde esta dicho archivo, la consola solo va a buscar el archivo en las variables de entorno y obviamente no lo va a encontrar.
En el caso de spotify y otros programas que solo escribes su nombre y se ejecutan, eso se debe a que el programa al instalarse añade el ejecutable a las variables de entorno del sistema por eso no hace falta mas que escribir el nombre del programa. Los videojuegos no suelen añadirse a las variables de entorno, así que asegurate de decirle a la consola la ubicación completa del archivo.

Comment: Para sumar a la respuesta, la consola también va a buscar en la carpeta actual si solo indicas el nombre